# how do make UI for getting smilies into my edittext?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext

I am having a notes app,in that i have to take smilies into my edittext where the cursor i point, for that i have to take list of smilies placed at top or pin to any place to emulator in edittext Activity.how come i disign UI for taking smilies(list of pngs,shown like grid view).or if any idea let me know? 
 task is: while typing in edit text, place the corsor to insert smilies and open any pin(button)to show smilies list and do select on one smilies and has to place in my text.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert smily image into spannableText which in turn you have to set into edittext 
here code hints:

```
public SpannableStringBuilder addSmily(Drawable dd) {

    happySmileys.setBounds(0, 0, dd.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            dd.getIntrinsicHeight());
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    builder.append(":-)");
    builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(dd), builder.length()
            - ":-)".length(), builder.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return builder;
}
```

above function return a spannableString which u can set like this

```
 Drawable dd=getResources().getDrawable(R.id.ursmily_icon);  
 edittext.settext(addSmily(dd));
```

enjoy with coding!

here is the reference project [adding sppannable to Edittext](https://github.com/krishnalalstha/Spannable)

Comment: Thank for reply, i already tried that code. i want to open the list of smilies from any button and select one it has to placed that in edit text.

Comment: for that use grid view where u set image(list of smily image). and for u, grid view should be invisible initially and when u click on any button make grid view visible.  after that override onItemclick to add selected smily where u want.

Comment: m happy that i cud help u. if my answer is right  for u den u can check as a accepted answer. which might be useful to others too. so ur accepted rate will be high after all You will be benefited.